newbie moving from applescript to extend script trying to round corners
I am pretty comfortable with scripting Indesign using Applescript, now I want to learn extendscript, & idjs sripting, I am an absolute beginer with both.
Below I have managed to cobble together a basic setup, but I think iv'e mixed the above styles into one script, as it feels and looks very awkward. can someone please show me how to tidy this mess up so I can see how it should be, and learn from the correct way.
The script runs how i'd like it to, but fails at rounding the rectangles corners, in applescipt I would use "convert shape given convert to rounded rectangle", in jsx I managaed to have my code round a rectangle as per below.
var myDoc = app.documents.add();
var rect =myDoc.rectangles.add({geometricBounds : [0,0,45,90]}) ;
rect.convertShape(ConvertShapeOptions.CONVERT_TO_ROUNDED_RECTANGLE, 8);

but I cant figure out how to incorporate it intomy other code, which is this
let myInDesign = require("indesign");
let app = myInDesign.app;
//let myLayer = myDoc.layers.item("Layer 1");

//************* Create Page Size *************
var myDoc = app.documents.add();
  with (myDoc.documentPreferences) {
      
pageHeight = "120 mm";
 pageWidth = "235 mm";
  pagesPerDocument = 1;

winHeight = "45 mm";
 winWidth = "90 mm";
  winInLeft = "20 mm";
   winUpBottom = "55 mm";  // up from bottom 20mm //

var marginPreferences = app.marginPreferences
 marginPreferences.bottom = "17mm";
  marginPreferences.left = "10mm";
   marginPreferences.right = "10mm";
    marginPreferences.top = "10mm";

app.activeDocument.zeroPoint = [0, 0];


//************* WINDOW SIZE & POSITION ************* LAYER INDEX 1
windowLayer = "Window";
 targetLayer=myDoc.layers.itemByName(windowLayer);
  myDoc.layers.add ({name:windowLayer});
   targetLayer=myDoc.layers.itemByName(windowLayer);

var rect =myDoc.rectangles.add({geometricBounds : [0,0,winHeight,winWidth] , strokeColor : myDoc.colors.itemByName("Keyline") , strokeWeight : "0.25" , overprintStroke : true ,});
rect.move([winInLeft, winUpBottom]);


rect.convertShape(ConvertShapeOptions.CONVERT_TO_ROUNDED_RECTANGLE, "8");    //************* script stops here.  

;

//************* ENV SIZE ************* LAYER INDEX 2
keylineLayer = "Keyline";
 targetLayer=myDoc.layers.itemByName(keylineLayer);
  myDoc.layers.add ({name:keylineLayer});
   targetLayer=myDoc.layers.itemByName(keylineLayer);
    var rect =myDoc.rectangles.add({geometricBounds : [0,0,pageHeight,pageWidth] , strokeColor : myDoc.colors.itemByName("Keyline") , strokeWeight : "0.25" , overprintStroke : true ,});
;

//});
    
}



Try removing the quotes from the  8 (i.e. use 8 instead of "8")

thanks for replying, I tried that and an error is thrown, which is

Not sure what the error is. You say  rect.convertShape(ConvertShapeOptions.CONVERT_TO_ROUNDED_RECTANGLE, 8); works, but rect.convertShape(ConvertShapeOptions.CONVERT_TO_ROUNDED_RECTANGLE, "8"); doesn't, hence my suggestion. Do all the test documents you tried use mm as measurement units?

thanks for replying cybernetic, which throws this error,   "UXPScript Error String: ConvertShapeOptions is not defined",  so where and how would I define it?

Just in case, here is the fixed Kurt's JSX code:
// Function to create a new document with specified preferences
function createDocument(w, h) {
    var myDoc = app.documents.add();
    myDoc.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.MILLIMETERS;
    myDoc.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.MILLIMETERS;
    myDoc.documentPreferences.pageWidth = w;
    myDoc.documentPreferences.pageHeight = h;
    myDoc.documentPreferences.pagesPerDocument = 1; // ?
    return myDoc;
}

// Function to add a layer if it doesn't already exist
function ensureLayer(doc, layerName) {
    var layer = doc.layers.itemByName(layerName);
    if (layer.isValid == false) layer = doc.layers.add({name: layerName});
    return layer;
}

// Function to create a rectangle with rounded corners
function createRoundedRectangle(doc, layer, bounds, cornerRadius) {
    var rect = doc.rectangles.add({
        geometricBounds: bounds,
        // strokeColor: doc.colors.itemByName("Keyline"),
        strokeWeight: 0.25,
        overprintStroke: true,
        itemLayer: layer
    });
    rect.convertShape(ConvertShapeOptions.CONVERT_TO_ROUNDED_RECTANGLE, undefined, undefined, cornerRadius);
    return rect;
}

// Main Script
(function main() {
    var myDoc = createDocument(235, 120);
    var windowLayer = ensureLayer(myDoc, "Window");
    var keylineLayer = ensureLayer(myDoc, "Keyline");

    // Adding window rectangle
    createRoundedRectangle(
        myDoc,
        windowLayer,
        [0, 0, 45, 90],
        8
    ).move([20, 55]);

    // Adding keyline rectangle
    createRoundedRectangle(
        myDoc,
        keylineLayer,
        [0, 0, myDoc.documentPreferences.pageHeight, myDoc.documentPreferences.pageWidth],
        0 // No rounding for keyline
    );
})();

There were the several problems.

Skipped the two arguments undefined, undefined, here:

rect.convertShape(ConvertShapeOptions.CONVERT_TO_ROUNDED_RECTANGLE, undefined, undefined, cornerRadius);

See the documentation:
https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign-latest/#Rectangle.html


If you want to use the color 'Keyline' you have to create the color first, since it's a new document, unlikely it has this color already. Otherwise you will get an error at this line:

strokeColor: doc.colors.itemByName("Keyline"),


This way to create/pick a layer doesn't work:

try {
    layer = doc.layers.itemByName(layerName);
} catch (e) {
    layer = doc.layers.add({name: layerName});
}

The first line will always get you some 'true' value, even if the document has no such layer. And the catch line will newer be activated. You have to check if the layer is a valid layer via the layer.isValid option.
Also:
InDesign can use current measurement units. You don't have to calculate them every time from the points (as in Illustrator). You can set the units for the document and use them.
myDoc.viewPreferences.horizontalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.MILLIMETERS;
myDoc.viewPreferences.verticalMeasurementUnits = MeasurementUnits.MILLIMETERS;

These lines are from UXP-scripts:
const myInDesign = require("indesign");
const app = myInDesign.app;

InDesign 2014 can't run UXP-scripts (if my memory serves me right). I don't know, perhaps it gets you no error. But it's just redundant for JSX-scripts anyway.

thank you Yuri, the explanation and time given is very much appreciated, as a novice in extend script this type of learning is invaluable., i see that the 2 versions of extend and UXP dont play well with each other, in your experience would you suggest I start with the true tried and tested extend script, or branch away to UXP

If you're using InDesign 2014 then probably you have no choice. There are only JSX and CEP (which is a modern web interface as a front end + jsx-script as a back end). I'm not an expert in UXP. I heard there were some limitations, I don't know if they are solved already. For practical purposes I'd recommend to use JSX. And there are thousands examples of JSX scripts you can learn with. But for educational purposes and for the future UXP looks promising. It's a nice modern version Javascript, it's worth to know it. JSX is a legacy, it still works but it's something almost like COBOL nowadays )


// Import
const myInDesign = require("indesign");
const app = myInDesign.app;

// Function to create a new document with specified preferences
function createDocument() {
    let myDoc = app.documents.add();
    with (myDoc.documentPreferences) {
        pageHeight = 120 * 2.83465;  // mm to points conversion (1 mm = 2.83465 points)
        pageWidth = 235 * 2.83465;
        pagesPerDocument = 1;
    }
    return myDoc;
}

// Function to add a layer if it doesn't already exist
function ensureLayer(doc, layerName) {
    let layer = null;
    try {
        layer = doc.layers.itemByName(layerName);
    } catch (e) {
        layer = doc.layers.add({name: layerName});
    }
    return layer;
}

// Function to create a rectangle with rounded corners
function createRoundedRectangle(doc, layer, bounds, cornerRadius) {
    let rect = doc.rectangles.add({
        geometricBounds: bounds,
        strokeColor: doc.colors.itemByName("Keyline"),
        strokeWeight: 0.25,
        overprintStroke: true,
        itemLayer: layer
    });
    rect.convertShape(ConvertShapeOptions.CONVERT_TO_ROUNDED_RECTANGLE, cornerRadius);
    return rect;
}

// Main Script
(function main() {
    let myDoc = createDocument();
    let windowLayer = ensureLayer(myDoc, "Window");
    let keylineLayer = ensureLayer(myDoc, "Keyline");

    // Adding window rectangle
    createRoundedRectangle(
        myDoc, 
        windowLayer, 
        [0, 0, 45 * 2.83465, 90 * 2.83465], // Convert mm to points
        8
    ).move([20 * 2.83465, 55 * 2.83465]);

    // Adding keyline rectangle
    createRoundedRectangle(
        myDoc, 
        keylineLayer, 
        [0, 0, myDoc.documentPreferences.pageHeight, myDoc.documentPreferences.pageWidth],
        0 // No rounding for keyline
    );
})();


thank you Kurt, this is much clearer, I see functions are the goto as in applescript, makes alot of sense, its good to see I am in the right zone, just alot learn,  I saved this script as a idjs script and ran from within Indesign 2014 19.3, the code throws an error on line 29, saying invalid parameter, can you explain why this is, as the rest of the code seems to folllow a rigid uniformity
